Forcing axiom for Mathias forcing
Given a poset $\mathbb{P}$, let $\mathsf{FA}(\kappa,\mathbb{P})$ denote the assertion that for every family of dense sets $\mathcal{D}$ with $|\mathcal{D}| = \kappa$, there is a filter $G \subseteq \mathbb{P}$ such that $G \cap D \neq \emptyset$ for all $D \in \mathcal{D}$.
Recall that the Mathias forcing $\mathbb{M}$ (not localised to a filter) is defined as
$$
\mathbb{M} := \{(s,A) : A \in [\mathbb{N}] ^\infty \wedge s \in [A]^{<\infty}\}, 
$$
and that $(t,B) \leq (s,A)$ iff $s \sqsubseteq t$, $t \setminus s \subseteq A$, and $B \subseteq A$. Note that $\mathbb{M}$ is not ccc, but it is proper.
Is $\mathsf{ZFC} + \neg\mathsf{CH} + \mathsf{FA}(\omega_1,\mathbb{M})$ equiconsistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$?

Isn't Mathias forcing ccc (since two conditions with the same stem must be compatible), which would imply that this follows from MA?

@AsafKaragila, the infinite sets in conditions can be disjoint, so not compatible even when stem is the same. So one can make an antichain from any almost disjoint family, so this is not ccc.

Perhaps it helps for others to mention that Mathias forcing has conditions $(s,A)$ where $s$ is a finite stem (a finite sequence of natural numbers) and $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ is infinite, with the order placing $(s,A)\leq(t,B)$ when $s$ extends $t$ inside $B$ and $A\subseteq B$.

@Joel: Oh. So the pairs are just $(s,A)$ where $s$ is a finite sequence and $A$ is a positive measure (with respect to the filter)? In this case I vaguely remember a dichotomy: either the forcing is ccc or else it collapses the continuum.

Mathias forcing is proper, and it has the pure decision property, meaning that you can decide any statement by shrinking the infinite set only.

It seems a natural candidate would be to start with CH and perform a countable-support $\omega_2$-iteration of Mathias forcing. Does this achieve your forcing axiom?

@Joel: Going by Lorenz's book, you're assuming that Mathias forcing is defined only with a Ramsey family, rather than an arbitrary filter? I think we're talking past each other using the same language with different meaning.

To me, Mathias forcing is defined exactly as I had said in my comment above, with no reference to any filter at all. The modified forms of it, defined relative to a filter, came later and are to be seen as qualified forms of Mathias forcing.
